# Reemplazar texto en varios ficheros dentor de un directorio y subdirectorios

Tags: procesamiento-de-texto

Estoy reemplazando texto contenido dentro de varios ficheros que se encuentra en un directorio y subdirectorios.

Quiero cambiar todas las cadenas **"coche"** y **"camión"** por **"vehículo"**

Estoy utilizando el GrepWin pero tengo que realizarlo 2 veces, una con **"coche"** y otra con **"camión"**

¿Alguna idea para realizarlo una única vez?

Me puede servir incluso por linea de comandos.

Comment: Por lo que veo GrepWin soporta búsquedas por expresiones regulares. Tienes que buscar `\b(coche|camión)\b` y cambiarlo por `vehículo`. (Si no usas `\b` para marcar bordes de palabras reemplazarías por ejemplo "cochera" por "vehículora".)

Comment: Ok, gracias, funciona

Comment: @juanrpozo puedes poner el comentario como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, GrepWin soporta búsquedas por expresiones regulares. Tienes que buscar `\b(coche|camión)\b` y cambiarlo por `vehículo`. (Si no usas `\b` para marcar bordes de palabras reemplazarías por ejemplo "cochera" por "vehículora".)